# Python function to add numbers from string

Tags: python

I was recently given this problem and tasked with coding a solution. My efforts so far have come close but not yet solved it.

Essentially, the problem involves creating a function which is passed a string of numbers (no validation required), for example '12345'.

I have to code the function (using Python preferably) that adds all the consecutive combination of digits. For the above example, this would be:

```
12345 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
+ 12 + 23 + 34 + 45
+ 123 + 234 + 345
+ 1234 + 2345
```

I have got some things working, for example:

```
#code to add the individual numbers
indivInts = [int(d) for d in stringNumber]
for i in indivInts:
        total += i

#code to add 12 + 123 + 12345, etc
for i in range(len(stringNumber)-2):
        s = ''.join([str(x) for x in indivInts[:i+2]])
        print('Adding loop 2: ' + s)
        total += int(s)
```

The issue I seem to be having is with the 'middle' numbers, ie 234, 34, etc.

The function should be able to take any string of an integer and still work.

Comment: Just to make sure: Should the first number in the sequence relaly be `123456` or `12345`?

Comment: Apologies, updated the Q now! taken out the 123456 - thanks Tobias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need the list of all possible substrings of the original number. You can use a list comprehension with two loops for the lower and upper bounds for this.

```
>>> s = "12345"
>>> [s[i:k+1] for i in range(0, len(s)) for k in range(i, len(s))]
['1', '12', '123', '1234', '12345', '2', '23', '234', '2345', '3', '34', '345', '4', '45', '5']
```

Then just get the sum of the previously generated list, converted to int:

```
>>> sum(map(int, _))
16755
```

In a single line:

```
>>> sum(int(s[i:k+1]) for i in range(0, len(s)) for k in range(i, len(s)))
16755
```

Or as a regular nested loop:

```
s = "12345"
r = 0
for i in range(0, len(s)):
    for k in range(i, len(s)):
        r += int(s[i:k+1])
print(r)
```

Comment: Nice code, +1. By the way you're missing "123456" (aka original number) in the sum :)

Comment: @Flo Whops, messed up my upper bound. Give me a second... Okay, should be fixed now.

Comment: This is much better than what I had been trying... thanks!